# volume group not showing in /dev , /dev/mapper

Tags: linux, lvm

We configure cluster with rhcs with storage partition.we created pv and vg. we can see pvdisplay and vgdisplay with all information about pv and vg which we created.

But we can not see vg file on /dev , /dev/mapper and therefore not able to format it and use.

please suggest to resolve this problem.

```
root@S1 mapper]# pvcreate /dev/mapper/mpath01
  Physical volume "/dev/mapper/mpath01" successfully created

[root@S1 mapper]# vgcreate cgdemo /dev/mapper/mpath01
  Clustered volume group "cgdemo" successfully created

[root@S1 mapper]# vgdisplay

  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               cgdemo
  System ID            
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  1
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  Clustered             yes
  Shared                no
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                0
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               1024.00 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              262143
  Alloc PE / Size       0 / 0  
  Free  PE / Size       262143 / 1024.00 GiB
  VG UUID               GgtiwS-b5M5-xQtA-7zJ2-swU9-m8Bw-vjM8IT
```

we set locking_type 3 in lvm.conf

Comment: Did you start `clvmd` daemon??

Comment: Yes clvmd is started. I can see vgdisplay and pvdisplay from both nodes.

Comment: What does `lvscan` show?

Comment: did you `vgchange -a y cgdemo`

Comment: yes, i tried with vgchange -a y cgdemo, cmd runs fine, but can

Comment: can't see volum group file in  /dev , /dev/mapper

Answer (score 6):

Your `vgscan` output shows that you have not allocated any space from the volume group to logical volumes:

```
Alloc PE / Size       0 / 0
```

You need to use `lvcreate` to create a logical volume in order to have a device to format eg

```
lvcreate -L50G -nvolumename cgdemo
```

to create a `50GB` volume named `volumename` using space from group `cgdemo`.

Comment: yes, currently no lvm created. But my confusion is that why i can't see vg in /dev or /dev/mapper

Comment: You don't see volume groups, you see volumes.  What could you possible do with a volume group device that would be useful?

Comment: i tried to add a lvm to that vg, but in that case also i can't see lvm or vg file in /dev , /dev/mapper. as per my understanding, if we create vg then vg file must show in /dev , /dev/mapper

Comment: you lvm will probably show up in /dev/cgdemo/lvname

Comment: @user1688045 I've never had a device for the volume group itself, it has always been a folder with logical volume devices in it.  You can try `vgscan --mknodes` but its manpage says it only creates dev entries for active logical devices, so it will probably not do anything.  Device mapper only creates `dm-*` devices for the logical partitions.

Comment: I also couldn't see my newly created volume group.
I started off [here](http://computernetworkingnotes.com/package-management/how-to-create-lvm-partition-in-linux.html) and drifted through [there](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11125/lvm-devices-under-dev-mapper-missing) and went through many more articles trying everything I could to see my volume group in /dev/.
DerfK's answer involves creating a new volume without specifying the missing path. That was the one command I was looking for. Now I have a new volume and the volume group is visible in /dev/.

Answer (score 0):

Volume groups are directories, created (I assume) as soon as you create at least one volume in that group.

You can try to create the directory by hand - use at your own risk.

> What could you possible do with a volume group device that would be useful?

I found this question because I though I would have to use a device in virt-install commands and libvirt XML files, but I had a second look now and they turned out to be group names and directories instead:

```
virt-install [...] pool=vmgrp,size=50,[...]

/dev/vmgrp/[...].img
```